# ¿Cómo usar correctamente la etiqueta "lang" en HTML?

Tags: html5

Por defecto mi editor crea las páginas HTML5 con la siguiente etiqueta *lang*:

```
<html lang="en">
```

Esta etiqueta debe indicar el texto predeterminado de la página (entiendo que el de su contenido principal), si bien en HTML5 se puede usar para indicar el lenguaje de un determinado contenedor, así puede llevarla un `div`, con un idioma diferente al indicado para la página.

Entiendo que ¿debemos indicar en la etiqueta el código correspondiente al del idioma de la página y cambiar este si cambia el idioma de esta? ¿Cómo nos afectaría tener un código de idioma incorrecto?

Comment: Como mínimo el atributo lang ayuda a los motores de búsqueda a identificar contenido en un idioma en particular. También sirve para que el software que lee las páginas a personas con dificultades de visión utilice una voz u otra. Respecto a si debes usarlo, claro, siempre que sea posible, da mayor valor semántico al código HTML.

Comment: @ordago la verdad es que pensé que podía tener alguna relación con los motores de búsqueda y la indexación de contenidos, no había caído en que también afecta a la accesibilidad...

Answer (score 1):

Es conveniente indicar el idioma en que está tu contenido, tanto a nivel de la página, como a nivel de bloques, en el caso de páginas que tengan contenido en varios idiomas.

En [w3.org se planteó una pregunta parecida a la tuya](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-language-declarations) y se reponde esto en resumen:

> Use siempre un atributo de idioma en la etiqueta `html` para declarar
>   el idioma predeterminado del texto de la página. Cuando la página
>   tenga contenido en otro idioma, agregue un atributo de idioma a un
>   elemento que rodee a ese contenido.
>
> ...
>
> Use elementos localizados para cuidar los valores de contenido y
>   atributos en el mismo elemento que están en idiomas diferentes.

Allí se dan pautas también para aplicar el atributo `lang` de forma correcta.

Por ejemplo, esto es incorrecto:

```
<a lang="es" title="Spanish" href="qa-html-language-declarations.es">Español</a>
```

Porque eso indicaría que lo que hay escrito en `title` está en español, cuando lo que está en español es el contenido del anchor. Por tanto, lo correcto sería esto:

```
<span title="Spanish"><a lang="es" href="qa-html-language-declarations.es">Español</a></span>
```

Para colocar elementos multi-idioma en un mismo párrafo por ejemplo, se puede usar `span`:

```
<p>Usted diría eso en chino como <span lang="zh-Hans">中国科学院文献情报中心</span>.</p>
```

### ¿Cuáles son las ventajas?

Son muchas.

Cuando especificas adecuadamente el idioma, el agente de usuario no tendrá dificultad en saber que tu contenido está en ese idioma. Ello repercute en la indexación correcta del sitio (motores de búsqueda), impacto positivo en el SEO.

También se da mayor facilidad para encontrar el sitio cuando se filtra por determinados idiomas.

Con los avances, hoy día mucha gente ya no lee, quiere que el ordenador le lea. Indicar un idioma facilitaría dicha lectura.

Esto está explicado y justificado detalladamente en el artículo titulado [***Idiomas en la Web*** de w3.org](https://www.w3.org/International/getting-started/language), el cual adjunto aquí de forma íntegra:

> #### ¿DE QUÉ SE TRATA?
>
> ¿Por qué usar el atributo idioma? explica en detalle por qué los
>   autores y desarrolladores de contenidos deben declarar el idioma.
>
> Los formatos basados en HTML y XML permiten declarar el lenguaje
>   natural (es decir, el lenguaje humano en lugar del lenguaje del
>   programa) de un documento o de una serie de textos, de modo que las
>   herramientas y las aplicaciones puedan utilizar esa información para
>   tareas sensibles al lenguaje. Esto incluye cosas como la aplicación de
>   fuentes apropiadas u otros estilos, cambiar la voz en la función de
>   "texto a voz", el corrector ortográfico, etc.
>
> Cuantos más contenidos se etiqueten y se haga correctamente con
>   información de idioma, más útiles y omnipresentes serán estas
>   aplicaciones.
>
> También es posible utilizar la información de idioma proporcionada por
>   un navegador o agente de usuario para garantizar que, cuando exista
>   una opción, los usuarios reciban los datos en su idioma preferido.
>
> #### DECLARAR EL IDIOMA
>
> Los autores de contenido necesitan saber cómo declarar el idioma de un
>   documento o texto en la tecnología Web con la que están tratando. HTML
>   utiliza el atributo lang, pero puede haber otras formas de marcado.
>   Por ejemplo, la mayoría de los formatos basados en XML, como XHTML,
>   SVG, SSML, etc., utilizan el atributo xml:lang definido por la
>   especificación XML.
>
> Los autores de contenido deben considerar si necesitan hacer una
>   diferencia entre declarar el idioma de un documento o fragmento de
>   texto para que las herramientas puedan procesarlo, y declarar la
>   audiencia a la que va dirigido un recurso (es decir, los metadatos).
>   Es posible que deba aplicar enfoques ligeramente diferentes para éstos
>   en HTML, por ejemplo. También debe evitar confundir las declaraciones
>   de idioma con los scripts y las declaraciones de codificación de
>   caracteres.
>
> Los autores de contenido y los webmasters también tendrán que saber
>   cómo utilizar los valores de los idiomas de forma estándar. El enfoque
>   estándar actual para las especificaciones de W3C es utilizar las
>   reglas contenidas en BCP 47. Esto sustituye a las especificaciones
>   anteriores, como la RFC 3066 y la RFC 1766, y va más allá de la
>   información disponible en el lenguaje ISO y las normas nacionales.
>   También debe utilizar el Registro de Subetiquetas de Idioma de IANA
>   para buscar etiquetas de idioma, en lugar de las especificaciones ISO.
>
> Es posible que los webmasters o las personas que trabajan con la
>   configuración del servidor también tengan que configurar el servidor
>   para que envíe con los archivos solicitados, información HTTP
>   relacionada con el idioma. Esto se hace normalmente como parte de la
>   negociación de contenido, donde el servidor envía al usuario una de
>   varias versiones disponibles de un documento dependiendo de la
>   configuración del navegador del usuario.
>
> #### NAVEGAR POR LOS SITIOS WEB UTILIZANDO LA INFORMACIÓN DEL IDIOMA
>
> Cuando se realiza una solicitud HTTP a un servidor, el cliente suele
>   enviar información sobre las preferencias de idioma. El servidor puede
>   utilizar esta información para devolver una versión del documento en
>   el idioma apropiado si existe tal alternativa.
>
> Los usuarios finales deben saber cómo comprobar que sus preferencias
>   de idioma estén configuradas correctamente, y cómo cambiarlas si no lo
>   están.
>
> Los webmasters deben saber cómo configurar su servidor para gestionar
>   la negociación de contenidos en función del idioma.
>
> Los diseñadores y desarrolladores de sitios web que trabajen con
>   sitios web multilingües deben plantearse cómo guiar a los visitantes
>   hacia los recursos adecuados.
>
> #### USO DE LA INFORMACIÓN DEL IDIOMA PARA LOS ESTILOS
>
> En la mayoría de navegadores, se puede utilizar CSS para aplicar
>   diferentes estilos de acuerdo con el idioma de un fragmento de texto.
>   Por ejemplo, dentro de un documento en inglés, puede asignar al texto
>   tailandés incrustado una fuente determinada y ajustes de altura de
>   línea adecuados en cualquier lugar donde aparezca, simplemente por el
>   hecho de etiquetar el contenido como tailandés.
>
> En CSS, los desarrolladores de hojas de estilo pueden utilizar
>   selectores con la propiedad content, allí donde sea posible, para
>   indicar automáticamente el idioma de destino de un enlace.
>
> #### DISEÑO DE LA INFORMACIÓN DEL IDIOMA EN FORMATOS DE MARCADO
>
> Los desarrolladores de especificaciones de marcado como Schema deben
>   considerar si el formato que están desarrollando incluye marcado para
>   permitir a los autores identificar el idioma principal del documento y
>   cualquier cambio en el idioma dentro del documento.
>
> Los desarrolladores de especificaciones de marcado como Schema también
>   deben tener claro cuándo es apropiado utilizar xml:lang en formatos
>   basados en XML, y cuándo deben crear un atributo o elemento diferente
>   para especificar la información del idioma.